# Does blocking method - "GetContext()" use CPU

Tags: .net

I am using .NET framework to design a http server.
I use http libraries of .NET.
.NET has GetContext() method which is a blocking method and will return a HttpListenerContext object.
On the website, it says: "This method blocks while waiting for an incoming request".
But, does it do busy waiting? Which means that does it use the CPU when it is waiting for incoming request? If not, what does it do? Release the use of CPU and let other process use the CPU?

Comment: The underlying call is a winapi one, HttpReceiveHttpRequest().  The non-overlapped version.  There are a handful of people in Washington State that knows what it actually does.  The likelihood that it is different from *any* winapi call that blocks are zero, +/-1%.  If you really care about then just use a profiler so you can *see* it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble deciphering the code (obtained via R#) and while it does do a `while(true)` in there, it is making the winapi call mentioned in the comments by Hans Passant, which probably blocks, so it's not necessarily doing busy waiting.

So like Hans Passant says, it is most likely doing the *right* thing unless your experience suggests otherwise. It shouldn't be blocking other processes from getting their fair-share of CPU time.

It will however block your current thread, so it you run this in the main thread of any type of app it will make it unresponsive, but other processes on your computer should be fine.